# How to get data from different steps

Tags: qaf

feature file:
[image]

StepDefinitionClass:

[image]

result:

[image]

How can I get the expected value(url)?

Comment: Did you tried setting `step.provider.sharedinstance` property to `true` as suggested in answer below?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `step.provider.sharedinstance` property to `true`. Refer [list of properties](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/properties_list.html) used by the framework.

Another alternate is using configuration manager to pass data between steps.

```
@QAFTestStep(description = "create new user")
public void createUser(){
   //do needful

   //store outcome to be used later
   getBundle().setProperty("newcreated.user", user);
}

@QAFTestStep(description = "print user")
public void printUser(){
   User user = (User)getBundle().getProperty("newcreated.user");
   //do the needful
}
```

This way is preferred over sharing data using class variables, because sharing through class variables will restrict steps to be in the same class.